# How to fix this it is showing Syntax error, ERROR 1064 (42000):

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a table with 2 foreign keys but unable to find the syntax error. Where do i need to make the changes?

```
create table Leave(
leaveId int primary key, noOfDays int, approverId varchar(50), requestorId varchar(50), 
Foreign key (approverId) References Approver (approverId), 
Foreign key(requestorId) References Requestor(requestorId)
);
```

These are the 2 tables create before creating leave table:

1. `create table Approver(approverId int primary key, approverName varchar(50));`
2. `create table Requestor(requestorId int primary key, requestorName varchar(50), noOfLeavesApproved int, approverId int, dateOfApplication date, Foreign key(approverId) References Approver(approverId));`

where can I make the changes for this syntax error?

It is showing the below error for the leave table

ERROR:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'Leave(leaveId int primary key, noOfDays int,
>   approverId varchar(50), requestorId' at line 1

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete error message in it.

Comment: @Alfabravo yeah done can u please suggest what changes need to be done.

Comment: Referenced and referencing column datypes must be the same AND you should publish the full create statement so we can seethe engines are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Leave is a reserved word in MySQL [(documentation)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-L). Therefore, it cannot be used by your objects

Change your table name to something else (example: `leave_request`) and it should work.

Comment: not quite - 'Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as described in Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names”: - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @P.Salmon you are completely right. Still, recommending to use names that must be permanently used between quotes feels like recommending holidays feeding a tiger or something like that :P